# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Increase Instance Disk Capacity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to use ElasticBeanstalk for an app with some big initial space requirements. It exceeds the default 8GB capacity of the EBS disk on the EC2 instances.

I tried to increase the disk capacity by using a bigger EC2 instance type. For instance, I used an m3.large, which AWS tells me should provide me with 1x32GB of storage.

However, when the Beanstalk environment launches, it still only shows 8GB. I tried to run the "resize2fs" command on the instance, but it didn't expand the volume to anything over 8GB.

Does anyone know how to get bigger instance storage on ElasticBeanstalk environments?

Comment: This question and answer appear to be more helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803107/how-can-i-just-increase-the-size-of-my-root-disk-on-aws-ec2-for-use-with-elastic?rq=1

Comment: I think this question and answer are more helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803107/how-can-i-just-increase-the-size-of-my-root-disk-on-aws-ec2-for-use-with-elastic?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 8 GB disk you are seeing is an EBS root volume mounted on `/`. That's the same no matter what instance type you use, which is why it still only shows 8 GB. The 32 GB of storage is ephemeral storage attached to the instance (not EBS). It's possible that it's not mounting automatically but it's certainly there.

Two options for you:

1. You can try to get that 32 GB ephemeral storage mounted.
2. You can create and mount a separate EBS volume of whatever size you
   need:
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-volume.html
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html

Either way, you will need to make whatever changes are required to point to this new storage, where ever you mount it in the filesystem. That can be by changing your configurations or creating symlinks from the old location to the new filesystem.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the answer! I didn't know that the listed disk space for instance types is actually ephemeral storage and not the EBS disk size. I'm surprised Amazon doesn't auto-mount the instance storage for you when creating your instances in the launch configuration.

Comment: To add to John's answer you can configure block device mappings on Elastic Beanstalk using the "BlockDeviceMapping" option in the "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration" namespace. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html. These can be put in .ebextensions http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html

Answer (score 32):

There is a better way to do this now using RootVolumeType and RootVolumeSize in aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration. Details are [here].[1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html)

Following is the relevant section from my cloudformation script to create elastic beanstalk

```
  {
    "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
    "OptionName": "RootVolumeType",
    "Value": "gp2"
  },
  {
    "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
    "OptionName": "RootVolumeSize",
    "Value": 25
  },
```

This can be easily achieved through ebextensions also.

Comment: I think this should now be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: While this answer solved my problem, could be great if you explain with details the reasons for the problem and what does the configuration that you expose. By the way, thank you!

Comment: Alert: It'll terminate your current instance and create the new one, so do backup any data.

Answer (score 29):

Example of solution for Elastic Beanstalk with ebextensions config:

**application-root-dir/.ebextensions/001-filesystem.config**:

```
option_settings:
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    RootVolumeType: gp2
    RootVolumeSize: "64"
```

Comment: Alert: It'll terminate your current instance and create the new one, so do backup any data.

Comment: yea this approach was smooth as butter

Answer (score 7):

If you are using AWS console, you can increase root volume with UI.

https://ap-southeast-2.console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home?region=ap-southeast-2#/environment/configuration/instance-traffic-scaling?environmentId=**your env id** [image: aws-eb-volumechange]